# Tableview row should change on pressed in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtableview

My delegate is image in tableview, How to change image of row which is selected 
onPressed and onReleased it should go back in it's original state.

```
itemDelegate: Image
            {
                id:item_id
                height: (tableView.height/(listmodel.count < 4 ? listmodel.count : 4))
                source:
                {
                    var activeRow = tableView.currentRow === styleData.row
                    (activeRow ? Image 1 : styleData.row % 2 ? (image 2): (image 3))
                }

                MouseArea
                {
                    id:table_mouse_id
                    anchors.fill: parent

                    onPressed:
                    {
                       source = image 4
                    }

                    onReleased:
                    {
                        tableView.currentRow = styleData.row
                    }
                }
```

Comment: use `states`. it's very clean and readable, create a `State` for the property you want to change and change the state of the `Image` when you press and release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `pressed` property of the `MouseArea`:

```
source: {
            var activeRow = tableView.currentRow === styleData.row;
            (activeRow ? table_mouse_id.pressed ? image4 //pressed
                                                : Image1 //active
                       : styleData.row % 2 ? (image2)  //odd
                                           : (image3)) //even
        }
```

Important note: you should remove the `onPressed` handler, as this will override the binding (which is probably also the reason it's not working in your current setup)

Comment: ok I will try this, @Amfasis Thank you for the answer, I have upvoted for your answer but my reputation score is less than 15 that's why it's not showing here but it is added.

Comment: If you think my answer is the solution you can mark is as accepted (see the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you don't know how). That will help others as well!